# SQL Server encountered one or more errors while retrieving information about publication 'C01_repl_01'

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am trying to establish a merge replication in SQL Server 2017 (edition) using SQL Server Management Studio 19.0.20196.0.

I am following the Microsoft documentation to achieve the goal, but I am getting an error after creating a publication. I can't open properties to edit the access list of that publication

> SQL Server encountered one or more errors while retrieving information about publication 'C01_repl_01'.
>
> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PublicationAccessListPage.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "CreatePubWizard" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. (mscorlib)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
> at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
> at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
> at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
> at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.FillResources(CultureInfo culture, ResourceSet& resourceSet)
> at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources(Object value, String objectName, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PublicationAccessListPage.InitializeComponent()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PublicationAccessListPage..ctor(CDataContainer dataContainer)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubPropertiesSheet.Init()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.PubPropertiesSheet..ctor(ReplicationSqlConnection conn)
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.LaunchPubPropSheet.PrepareToShow()

I have repeated the same steps in SQL Server 2022 (edition) and there was no error, but I want to keep SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Looks like this issue has been resolved in in SSMS 19.0.2 https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/3dba641e-a9a3-ed11-a81b-6045bd79fc6e

Comment: I have updated ssms to 19.0.2, the problem persists

Comment: thanks @MartinSmith , the version i used was 19.0.20196.0 , i upgrade to 19.0.20209.0 , now i can access the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @MartinSmith , the version i used was 19.0.20196.0 , i upgrade to 19.0.20209.0 , now i can access the properties of publication